# python - access post data using sys.stdin.read()

Tags: python, .htaccess, cgi, stdin

I'm running a simple python script on my webserver using .htaccess directives:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

I'm using sys.stdin.read() to access post data which is working fine on my development machine.

However, when uploading my script and .htaccess file to production, sys.stdin.read() returns an empty string, causing my script to fail.

Does anyone have a clue as to what the difference between the two setups might be?